# Generating events in a random order PHP

Tags: php, events, random

Basically what i want to do is this:

I have a number (i.e. 9) and a maximum range of 36.
I want to generate events on 9 out of 36 possibilities (exactly 9/36, no more, no less)
The number 9 is from a variable, 36 is 36 all the way.
I don`t want my 9 chances to occur at start, or at the end. I want it to be random.

Example.
I have 9 out of 36 chances to "shoot gun".

try 1/36  - miss

try 2/36  - shoot

try 3/36  - miss etc... , all the way up to 9 shots out of 36 possibile.

The order is not important, i just need all 9 to occur randomly across 36 tries.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: Sorry if i`m being ambiguos. Here is what my problem is:

I have an event, say, "shot". 
I want it to occur $occurace = 9 times, but randomly across 36 possibile chances for it to occur.

Like i said:

try1 - miss
try2 - shot
try3 - shot
...
try35 - miss
try36 - miss

Running the code again, i want this to change, like:

try1 - shot
try2 - miss
try3 - shot
...
try35 - miss
try36 - shot

I need 9 events to randomly occur in 36 chances, but i want them all to occur, not none or more than 9

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Do you just want to pick a number between 1 and 36 9 times?

Comment: Where do the `miss` and `shoot` come from?

Comment: if you just want random, then you should be okay with sometimes having all 9 at the start or all 9 at the end, because that's how random numbers work. Their distribution is random.

Comment: PHP has a fine random number generator, it can select random numbers in a range, and also select random elements from an array. I'm sure one of those will solve your problem, whatever it is.

Comment: Please provide more information as question seems to be quite confusing.

Comment: @Barmar , i want a random distribution of 9  events throughout 36 chances of their occurance. The miss and shoot are examples, i already have the code for the events but i want to make them occur randomly 9  times in 36 cases.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by an event. Do you have an array of 36 events, and you need to select 9 of them? In your example, there seem to be only 2 events, hit and miss. You take 9 shots, I don't understand where 36 fits into it.

Comment: He wants a series of 36 events, of which 9 (aka 1/4) of them need to be "shoot". The 9 "shoot events need to be placed randomly, but there MUST always be 9 "shoot" events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$spots = array();

while (count($spots) < 9) {
    $rand = rand(1,36);
    if (!isset($spots[$rand])) {
        $spots[$rand] = TRUE;
    }
}

$spots = $spots + array_fill(1, 36, FALSE);
ksort($spots);
```

There will always be 9 TRUE/Shoot spots, and the rest will be FALSE/Miss spots. It is truly random, they can be anywhere in the array.

A simple `foreach` across the array `$spots` will tell you when to "shoot"

Comment: No problem, although I should give you a heads-up that since you have a new account and you have a -5 on your first question, you may not be able to post a question until you answer some questions (and get good marks) on stackoverflow.

Comment: Also, I should mention that the `ksort()` is a must, without it all the "shoots" will happen at the beginning.

Comment: Yes, figured that out, i just tested the code you wrote and it works flawlessly. It suites my needs in the best way possibile :)